# How to resolve the gstreamer dependencies in arch linux

Tags: gstreamer, archlinux, wine, pacman-package-manager

Today I tried to install wine to be able to install roblox for my child, the problem is that after I unchecked multilib from /etc/pacman.conf , I keep getting the following

**error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing gstreamer (1.20.3-1) breaks dependency 'gstreamer=1.20.2' required by gst-plugins-base-libs
-> error installing repo packages**

I've been using Arch Linux for a long time and I'm quite experienced, but I don't know how to solve this error, I tried to search it on google, to install gstreamer with yay.
I think I should update the system with the command:

**sudo pacman -Syu**

but it takes way too long because I don't have a very good internet, so I think there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating `gst-plugins-base-libs`

`sudo pacman -Syu gst-plugins-base-libs`
then try to install lib32-gstreamer.

Edit: If it doesn't work, updating your system may be a option.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem with:

```
sudo pacman -Syu gst-plugins-base-libs gst-libav gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good
```